# I want to play a welcome voice when my web page loads but don't on reload the web page

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have Added an auto-play welcome voice or audio in my web page for new visitors.But when, visitors reload the web page the welcome voice plays again.I don't want to play it again when visitor reload the web page. Can anyone can guide me?
My code is here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
 audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'filepath/audiofile.wav');
 audioElement.play();
</script>
```

Comment: What event do you expect to exist that separates "reload" from "went to another page then came back to my page"?  You can set storage items, but these depend on user settings, just like cookies...

Comment: OMG, I HATE it when I go to a website and my machine blurts out some message or starts playing music. Pleeze consider that not all of your new visitors are sitting alone in an empty room.

Comment: @abiessu I want to play that welcome message only once for one visitor and if he/she reload my page the voice should't play again.

Comment: @DOK That is slow and soft voice and duration is also short.

Comment: A lot of people do not want to have their phone or their laptop suddenly start talking on the bus or in the restaurant or at work. And we will leave your website and never come back. See, we don't know that the sound will be short, and that it will never happen again.

Comment: @DOK You are right and i am agree with you only in-case of informative and General sites.Actually,that is a promotional site of a product obviously if someone visit my site he would already know he is checking a product page and every company makes attractive the promotional page. so, i don't think that a busy person can check a home product's website during his office or work-time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do is set a cookie that works as a flag to check if the page has loaded before or not,

```
<script>

    function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays)
    {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime()+(exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
    }

    function getCookie(cname)
    {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) 
      {
      var c = ca[i].trim();
      if (c.indexOf(name)==0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
      }
    return "";
    }


    window.onload=function(){
    if(getCookie('hasPlayed') != null){

    var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
     audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'filepath/audiofile.wav');
     audioElement.play();
    setCookie('hasPlayed', true, NUMBER-OF-DAYS-TO-KEEP-COOKIE);
    }

};

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use web storage to know if the page is visit for the first time or is a reload.
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage

Comment: This depends on user settings